# Merge resources into app.xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mergeddictionaries

Targeting .NET Framework 4.0.

I have a UserControl (`usercontrol.xaml`) with some resources that I would like to be accessible from the application's resources (`app.xaml`). (My UserControl is instantiated in `MainWindow.xaml`.)

So far I've tried this in app.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="usercontrol.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

But Visual Studio complains about this:
*An error occurred while finding the resource dictionary "usercontrol.xaml".*

**Q:** How can I add my UserControl's resources to the application so that I can do this in runtime:

```
Style style = FindResource("SomeStyleDefinedInUserControl") as Style;
```

Comment: Why do you define styles in a usercontrol ? Can't you put your styles in a separate resource dictionary ?

Comment: No particular reason, I guess. The resources shouldn't be there?

Comment: If you want to share them, no. Use a resource dictionary and add it to the merged dictionaries of App like you did.

Comment: Well, that's pretty much the right answer. Can't accept a comment though... :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your styles in a separate resource dictionary if you want to share them.

Then, add the resource dictionary to the merged dictionary of App like you did :

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="usercontrol_styles.xaml"/>
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

The styles are now accessible from anywhere within your application.